# I have a Dynamic WebTable where i need to select any Two checkbox randomly how to do that Any Leads

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario:

I have a WebTable where i go and enter the Search Criteria and based on the Search Criteria the Matching records appears. Then i Need to select 2 checkbox from the table .

My Question is - The Code has the option to select checkbox but i need to select any Two checkbox and Second after selecting the checkbox i need to come out of the Loop..And there could be 2 or more rows in the WebTable

Below is my Code:

```
List chekcboxoptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'mat-checkbox-layout')]")); List DemandSelection = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@role='rowgroup']//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]"));

for(WebElement demandselection:DemandSelection)
            {


                     
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int index = random.nextInt(chekcboxoptions.size());
                    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 100)");
                    chekcboxoptions.get(index).click();  = If i
```

insert a break after selecting one checkbox it comes out of the loop but i need to select two checkbox .

HTML OF THE Web Table:

Continue  Back searchfilter_alt More Filters    Demand ID  Cargo  OD / BU  Load Port  Discharge Port  Laycan Start Date  Laycan End Date  GBPO Dead Line  4378SELTESTTECHMTESSINGAPOREHONGKONG2030-04-092040-06-152055-12-30 4379SELTESTTECHMTESSINGAPOREHONGKONG2030-04-092040-06-152055-12-30 4380SELTESTTECHMTESSINGAPOREHONGKONG2030-04-092040-06-152055-12-30 4381SELTESTTECHMTESSINGAPOREHONGKONG2030-04-092040-06-152055-12-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you should not iterate all the elements, just generate 2 random number and click the select option.

```
int randOne = random.nextInt(chekcboxoptions.size());
chekcboxoptions.get(randOne).click();
int randTwo = random.nextInt(chekcboxoptions.size());
chekcboxoptions.get(randTwo).click();
```

> Do not use for loop for this